# Ionic-3 Image Upload using FileTransfer Native to NodeJs server

Tags: node.js, http, ionic-framework, ionic2

I followed one of tutorial from @Simon_Grimm blogs. It's a simple Ionic image upload to Node.js. Everything is perfectly working except the upload. I can display image from the server into my Ionic Client, I can delete as well as. My HTTP request for delete and getting images are working perfectly. Only whenever I click the upload button it can't communicate with my backend. It populated the error where mention http_status = null, body = null etc. I could not understand why does not work? For file uploading to native File transfer. As far as I can fell my problem is that somehow my upload method could not trigger the HTTP request. 
I would be glad if anyone can guide me, please.

My image upload serveice provider is

image-upload-setting.ts, here is my uploadMethod. My error was triggered at this `return filetransfer callback (err)=>`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Http, Response} from "@angular/http";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { FileTransfer, FileUploadOptions, FileTransferObject } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';


@Injectable()
export class ImageUploadSettingsProvider {

  constructor(private http: Http, private transfer: FileTransfer, private file: File) {
    console.log('Hello ImageUploadSettingsProvider Provider');


  }



  imageUpload(imageData, desc){
    let requestUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/images/'+ 'upload'; 
    var destination = imageData; 

    var options: FileUploadOptions = {
          fileKey: 'file',
          chunkedMode: true,
          mimeType: 'multipart/form-data',
          params: { 'desc': desc }
    };
    const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
    return fileTransfer.upload(destination,requestUrl,options).then(
        (data)=>{
            console.log('ImageProvider Upload Data-',data); 
        },
        (err)=>{
            console.log( err ); 
        }
    )

  }; 



}
```

Its means that my uploadMethod `successfull .then((data)=>{})` doesn't work.

My html.ts is

```
onSubmit(form: NgForm){
  this.imageProvider.imageUpload(this.imageUrl, form.value.desc).then(
    (res)=>{
        form.reset(); 
    },
    (err)=>{
        console.log(err); 
    }
  );
};


 onTakePhoto(){

      const options: CameraOptions = {
                quality: 100,
                encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                correctOrientation: true,
                allowEdit: true,
                destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
                sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
           }

       this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData)=>{


/*
          let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
           this.imageUrl = base64Image   */


       this.imageUrl = imageData; 


    }, (err) => {
          const toast = this.toastCtr.create({
              message:'Could Not save the image. Please try again',
              duration:2500
            });
            toast.present();
            this.camera.cleanup();
        });

}
```

I tried to change the formate to base64. Unfortunately it doesn't work as well as. Then I uncomment it. Now I am pulling my hair since 1 week.

Thanks for your effort

Answer (score 0):

In ImageUploadSettingsProvider, try changing this

```
mimeType: 'multipart/form-data',
```

to this

```
mimeType: "image/jpg",
```

Comment: Hi @Sherif_Abdulmawala,
Thanks for reply. But I am sending file as a form data. If I send only image than I have to handle format like base64 Image Formate. This solution didn't help me. I have already changed. It doesn't trigger my http request.